# How to properly search Collection(Edm.String) in Azure Search?

Tags: azure, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I've just create a Collection field in Azure search that looks like:

```
[
    {"id" : 40, "name" : "Fantasy"},
    {"id" : 52, "name" : "Nonfiction"},
    {"id" : 53, "name" : "Paranormal"}
]
```

Now I'm having problems querying the field to filter, for example, for all the records that contain id: 40 or to search for all the records with name : "Fantasy"

I do manage to do it, specifically using search.ismatch but that way I'm basically treating the Collection as a string... If that's the case what is supposed to be the advantage of having a collection field?

Any input?

Comment: From the JSON, it looks more like a Collection(Edm.ComplexType) than a Collection(Edm.String). Are you evaluating the Complex Types private preview? It would help to see the relevant part of your index definition.

Comment: I'm creating the field as a Collection(Edm.String)... In the documentation I don't even see a Collection(Edm.ComplexType)... I assumed that by creating a collection the analyser your tokenize the array and therefore allow direct queries to each property. Do you suggest I create the index with a Collection(Edm.ComplexType) field?

Comment: @BruceJohnston I'm creating the index as   {
"name": "genres",
"type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
"searchable": true,
"filterable": true,
"retrievable": true,
"sortable": false,
"facetable": false,
"key": false,
"indexAnalyzer": null,
"searchAnalyzer": null,
"analyzer": "standard.lucene",
"synonymMaps": []
}

Comment: In that case, I don't understand how the JSON in your question corresponds to the index definition. If "name" is a Collection(Edm.String), why is it not an array in the JSON...?